# Margin formatting connected with elements and not browser window?

Tags: html, css

Good day! I ran into a peculiar problem today. It is a bit wierd, but I am actually very happy I ran into it, because now I get to learn something new.

It is in my understanding that the margin (we are talking about pure css positioning atm) is based on the container in which the element is in. 

For example if I have a `div` with `width X` and `height Y` and 2 paragraphs in it, when I style the paragraph to have `margin-top : 2%` it will be positioned after the 2% worth of pixels from the top.
 And it was logical for me that if there is no container, the browser will take into account the border of the window. Aperantly this understanding is wrong.

How did I come to this conclusion: Consider the following- a banner, 1% from the top, a log-in box 2% from the top and a content field 8% from the top. (There are also left margin values, but they are irrelevant because the solution to this is the solution to them aswell)

What actually happens is that the margin is taken after the last element, so this means that the log-in box is styled 2% after the menu box which means that it is styled with an offset which is the sum of all ofsets of all previous elements.

My question is how do I deal with it? How can I make the margins be taken for the border of the window, not for the previous element ?

Also, here is the source code, in case someone is interested in exactly what I have written:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<style>

    .menu {
    width:600px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
    margin-top:1%;
    margin-left:33%;
    float:left;
    }

    .login {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-left:87%;
    float:none;
    }

    .content {
    width:600px;
    min-height:300px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
     margin-top:1%;
    margin-left:33%;
    }

    .flush {
        clear: both;
    }

    body {
    background-color:#daeaf1;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu"></div><div class="login"></div><div class="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you found that margin is related to HTML elements flow that is right.

If you want to set elements out of flow then you should play with position, top, left, right and bottom properties.

probably in your case you should want to use:

```
.login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 20px;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, this does the trick. I will do some research on relative, fixed, absolute and static positioning.